# Inserting one matrix into other in la4j

Tags: java, sparse-matrix

I'm using la4j library. I've got this code:

```
Matrix sparse = new CCSMatrix(3, 3);
Matrix newSparse = new CCSMatrix(4, 4);
sparse.setAll(5);
newSparse.insert(sparse);
System.out.println(sparse.toCSV());
System.out.println(newSparse.toCSV());
```

The output now is:

```
5,000, 5,000, 5,000
5,000, 5,000, 5,000
5,000, 5,000, 5,000

0,000, 0,000, 0,000, 0,000
0,000, 0,000, 0,000, 0,000
0,000, 0,000, 0,000, 0,000
0,000, 0,000, 0,000, 0,000
```

Why *newSparse* matrix doesn't contain *sparse* matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the operations in la4j are out-of-place by default. So you have to do something like this:

```
Matrix sparse = new CCSMatrix(3, 3);
Matrix newSparse = new CCSMatrix(4, 4);
sparse.setAll(5);
newSparse = newSparse.insert(sparse);
```

Comment: That was so easy... Thank you very much :)